# What combination attacks exist and which one is strongest?

Tags: phantasy-star-4

Are there 14 or 15 combination attacks in *[Phantasy Star IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantasy_Star_IV:_The_End_of_the_Millennium)*? What is the most powerful combination attack?

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice summary of combinations on [phantasy-star.net](http://www.phantasy-star.net/psiv/combos.html), stating **14**:

> > Ever since PSIV was, there have been
> >     claims that there are more than the
> >     fourteen combos listed below.
> >     Instruction books and hintbooks claim
> >     that there are fifteen or more.
> >     However, in all the years the game has
> >     been out, **no legitimate combo** has been
> >     published on the net, **other than** the
> >     ones below.
>
> Black Hole    - Negatis /-\
>   (Gra,Gigra,Nagra)
>
> Blizzard  - (Wat,Giwat,Nawat) /-\
>   (Zan,Gizan,Nazan) or (Wat,Giwat,Nawat)
>   /-\ Hewn
>
> Circuit Break - Hijammer /-\ Tandle
>
> Conduct Thunder   - (Wat,Giwat,Nawat) +
>   Tandle
>
> Destruction   - Deban + Megid + Legeon +
>   Positron Bolt
>
> Firestorm     - (Zan,Gizan,Nazan) /-\
>   (Foi,Gifoi,Nafoi) or (Foi,Gifoi,Nafoi)
>   /-\ Hewn or (Zan,Gizan,Nazan) /-\
>   Flaeli or Flaeli /-\ Hewn
>
> Grand Cross   - Crosscut /-\ Efess
>
> Holocaust - Savol /-\ Diem
>
> Lethal Image  - Death + Illusion
>
> Paladin Blow  - Rayblade /-\ Astral
>
> Purify Light  - Holyword /-\ Efess
>
> Shooting Star - Burst Rocket +
>   (Foi,Gifoi,Nafoi) or Burst Rocket +
>   Flaeli
>
> Silent Wave   - Phonomezer /-\ Airslash
>
> Triblaster    - Wat /-\ Foi /-\ Tsu
>
> where  () means any skill or technique
>   within may be used; /-\ means the
>   order of the skills or techniques does
>   not matter; and
>   + means the skills or techniues must be performed in the specified order;

To answer the second part of your question, the most powerful combination is **Destruction**, as described in [this article](http://www.psalgo.com/phantasy-star-iv/feeve.html).

Comment: I'd like to add that some combos like Firestorm or Blizzard get stronger if you user the stronger versions of the spells (Nafoi instead of Foi, in example).

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing a youtube video with a rare combo involving one of the female characters (I'm pretty sure Alys) running in front of the bosses really fast and slashing them while a spell was going.......I'd never found it when I owned the game. ....I'm pretty sure it was Alys so you couldn't use it later. Like her doing a quick slash with her boomerang weapon.  So there is a legitimate 15th combo unless this was like a homebrew hack but it looked legit.

Comment: Could you find this video and confirm the names?